# Best way to turn an array values to be used as a method attributes?

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => bg
        [1] => service
        [2] => index
        [3] => index
    )
```

And I want to use those values to a method like this:

```
(new UrlLibry())->SetUrl('service', 'index', 'index');
```

Of course I can `array_shift($array);` to remove the first element `bg` which I do not need it.

**Important. The array could be with unlimited values. This one is with 4, but it could be with 40. So I need some universal approach.**

I tried many things found in StackOverFlow, but so far no luck. My latest code is this one:

```
$urlsData = implode(' ', array_map(function ($k, $v) { return "'". $v . "',"; },
    array_keys($array), $array
));
```

But this one is it generating me one value with one string like this `'service', 'index', 'index',` and I need something like this `$value0, $value1, $value3... unlimited values`
So the final result should be something like this:

```
(new UrlLibry())->SetUrl($value0, $value1, $value2, $value3 // and more);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As of PHP 7.4](https://laravel-news.com/spread-operator-in-array-expressions-coming-to-php-7-4) you can use the `Spread-Oprator`:

```php
$array = ["A", "B", "C"];


function myFunction($a, $b, $c) { 
    echo "a: $a, b: $b, c: $c";
}

myFunction(...$array);
```

Try it online: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2bbb16b293ea5fce32f4b34a3df457a65a6dfb75

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for I don't know why it was so hard to find it :/